# Resizing an OpenGL texture shared with OpenCL (in OS X 10.9)

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, opencl

I have an OpenCL kernel that renders to an OpenGL texture, which I resize to match the window size as it changes. I used to do this inside my resize callback by releasing the cl_mem object, calling glTexImage2D, and recreating the cl_mem:

```
if (m_clBuffer != NULL)
    CALL_CL_GUARDED(clReleaseMemObject, (m_clBuffer));
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_glTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
m_clBuffer = clCreateFromGLTexture(m_clContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, m_clBuffer, &err);
```

This worked fine on OS X 10.8, but after upgrading to 10.9, resizing the window caused all subsequent kernel calls to make my monitors flicker black and freeze for a few minutes. I take that to mean my OpenCL context got corrupted somehow, but none of the OpenCL calls report errors. This bug happens both under GLUT and inside a QT QGLWidget subclass.

I finally managed to get around this crash by deleting the old OpenGL texture and creating an entirely new one before calling glTexImage2D. It doesn't seem like I should need to do that. Is this a bug in the new OpenCL/OpenGL implementation in 10.9, or should I have been doing that all along?

Comment: Where is your CL/GL synchronization? Since GL does not have to finish the `glTexImage2D (...)` command immediately, you need to make sure the command finishes before using it in CL. `glFinish (...)` is the most portable technique for doing this, but `glFlush (...)` may be sufficient in some cases.

Comment: I was under the impression that glTexImage2D takes effect immediately--for instance, when you pass in texture data you can deallocate it once glTexImage2D returns (though I suppose it could be buffered somewhere in system ram). I have glFinish() before my clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects calls, of course.

Comment: In any case, I tried adding glFinish() and I get the same crashing behavior.

Comment: BTW, slide 36 of this presentation by an NVIDIA engineer doesn't include explicit synchronization between the glTexImage2D and clCreateFromGLTexture calls: http://sa09.idav.ucdavis.edu/docs/SA09_GL_interop.pdf

Comment: Julian, you don't need synchronization between glTextImage2D and clCreateFromGLTexture. You do need it for the Acquire/Release calls.